# CQLSH is not executing and Connection Refused

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I am unable to execute cqlsh command. I am new to cassandra. I have followed the previous threads. Still unable to execute cqlsh command. Please help me to figure out the issue. Here is the error when I run CQLSH,

```
[root@Kar bin]# cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers',
    {'127.0.0.1': error(111,
    "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. 
     Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Thanks,
Karthick

Comment: check that Cassandra is running... you need to look into system.log to find if there was any error during startup

Comment: You also probably don't want to run cqlsh (or Cassandra for that matter) as root.

Comment: Hi Alex, Cassandra services is running fine.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I have tried to run cqlsh as a root user as well as a Cassandra user. Still I am unable to get going.

Answer (score 0):

What are the values of your `listen_address` and `broadcast_address`?

```
$ grep _address conf/cassandra.yaml | grep -v "\#"
listen_address: 169.254.93.1
rpc_address: 169.254.93.1
```

In my case, 169.254.93.1 is the only address that Cassandra will bind on port 9042.  Therefore, just running `cqlsh` (without specifying the IP) only works if they are mapped to the home IP of `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

Therefore, I will need to specify `169.254.93.1` to connect.

```
$ bin/cqlsh 169.254.93.1 -u flynn -p reindeerFlotilla
Connected to TheGrid at 169.254.93.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
flynn@cqlsh>
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, please find the listen_address and rpc_address entries below,[root@Kar-Casa03 cassandra]# grep _address conf/cassandra.yaml | grep -v "\#"
listen_address: 192.168.219.62
rpc_address: 192.168.219.62

Comment: [root@Kar-Casa03 cassandra]# grep _address conf/cassandra.yaml | grep -v "\#"
listen_address: 192.168.219.62
rpc_address: 192.168.219.62
broadcast_rpc_address: 192.168.219.62

Comment: @Karthick Have you tried executing `cqlsh 192.168.219.62` ?

Comment: Yes Aaron, I have tried executing cqlsh 192.168.219.62. Still the same unfortunately